# Refreshing RDD in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have implemented Spark Streaming which receives data from Kafka. There is a RDD which loads data from Database to perform operations against incoming data from streaming. However, I want to refresh the RDD periodically to retrieve any changes in the Data source (Database). Is there any way to refresh / reload the data?

Answer (score 2):

If you perform the reading of the database in a transform, you can also pass the time as an argument:

`.transform((rdd, time) => refreshDbTable(rdd, time))`

Then if you want to refresh every 15mins;

```
def refreshDbTable(rdd: RDD, time: Time) = {

  if (time.isMultipleOf(Minutes(15))) {

    // drop the temp table

    // re-register the temp table 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can broadcast the rdd, and use a timer to periodic update the broadcast.